# 'Business' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django, django-registration

I've changed the django-registration code. I am inserting data in `UserProfile` and `Business` model during signup. 
Data is saving in `UserProfile` Model.

```
#TODO: saving contact and address field data into UserProfile
user_profile = new_user.get_profile()
user_profile.user = new_user
user_profile.contact, user_profile.address = contact, kwargs['address']
user_profile.save()
```

Following code does not work.Getting this error.
`'Business' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.`

```
#TODO: saving business field data into Business Model
user_business = Business()
user_business.owner = new_user
user_business.name = business
user_business.save()
```

thanks
UPDATE

```
class Business(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
owner = models.ManyToManyField(User)
created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=datetime.now)
modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=datetime.now)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']

def save(self):
    self.modified = datetime.now()
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.name, instance=self)
    super(Business, self).save()
```

Comment: Could you please show the model structure.

Comment: There is a problem with the custom save method, I think. But, I am not sure (still investigating). You can just for a chance try removing it and running your code.

Comment: What signals are called for `Business`? Please post any and all of them.

Comment: FWIW, `created` should use `auto_now_add=True` and `modified` should use `auto_now=True`. Remove `default` from both.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your custom code to :

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.modified = datetime.now()
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
    super(Business, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**UPDATE**

@no_access I think there is a problem in the process of assigning the `User` instance to the `ManyToManyField` in `Business`. I suspect that the `ManyToManyField` field isn't getting the reference to the `User` instance that is being created. The `intermediate` table of `ManyToManyField` field needs a proper `User` object to reference to. So, I think here lies the problem.

Comment: There is no problem with custom save method. I tried your method too. But no luck.

Comment: @no_access that may have not fixed your problem here, but you *need* to override `save` this way (i.e. with `*args` and `**kwargs`). Otherwise, you'll break a bunch of other stuff in Django that calls save on your models (admin in particular).

Comment: @no_access Firstly, have you written custom code for slugify? If you have used the default one, you need not supply `instance=self` to it.
Secondly, you need not place the statement `self.modified = datetime.now()` after the changes of the model as per the comment of `Chris Pratt` in the question.
Lastly, is this the complete code that is related to the `Business` model?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Could the update in my answer be the fault/problem?

Comment: @SandipAgarwal: Nailed it. I completely missed that. @no_access: you need to assign the user with `user_business.owner.add(new_user)` but you have to call `user_business.save()` *first*.

Comment: @SandipAgarwal noticed it, I was just fleshing out his update. Go ahead and give the credit to him.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Exactly. Thanx for your confirmation. :-) BTW, I won't mind a vote up from any one of you. :-p